# converting a pointer to unsigned char to an NSImage

Tags: char, nsdata, unsigned, 16-bit

I have a structure which includes a pointer to a data set, which in this case is a 16-bit grayscale image.  I want to convert this data to an NSImage so that I can display it, and then save it as a .TIF file.  The route from the manuals appears to be something like:

```
(Create *myNSImData from frame->image, which is a pointer)
NSImage *TestImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData : myNSImData];
(display TestImage, save it, whatever else)
[TestImage release];
```

I am lost as to how to create the NSData object and assure it contains the array of 16-bit data.  Attempts to recast the pointer give warnings and no data.  I could simply increment the pointers, transferring one byte at a time from frame->image to the data object, but I don't understand how to communicate the array structure to the data object.  Any ideas?
Thanks

MORE ATTEMPTS USING YOUR SUGGESTION
I can convert this data to a .TIF file in the following manner:

```
for (uint32 row = 0 ; row < MaxHeight ; row++)  
{
    for (uint32 column = 0;column< MaxWidth;column++)
    {
        tempData = (uint8_t)*frame->image;  //first byte
        *frame->image++;
        buf[2 * column + 1] = (unsigned char) tempData;
        tempData = (uint8_t)*frame->image;  //second byte
        *frame->image++;
        buf[2 * column] = (unsigned char) tempData;
    }
    TIFFWriteScanline(tiffile,buf,row,0);
}
```

With the .TIF file thus generated, I can create an NSImage and display it:

```
NSImage *TestImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:inFilePath] autorelease];
[viewWindow setImage: TestImage];
```

My question now becomes - can I create an NSData object that I can display in the same way? I have tried the following (product is the height*width of the image):

```
NSData *ReadImage = [[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: frame->image length:2*product]  autorelease] ;
NSImage *NewImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:ReadImage] autorelease];
NSSize newSize;
newSize.height = MaxHeight; //height of the image
newSize.width = MaxWidth; //width of the image
[NewImage setSize:newSize];
[viewWindow setImage: NewImage];
```

When I try this, nothing displays.  I have also tried creating an array of uint16_t which has the data, and serving up the pointer to that - again, nothing displays. Any ideas? E.g. do I have to tell the NSData that I am using 2 bytes per pixel, or something like that? Thanks Monty Wood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an `NSData` object containing a block to which you have a pointer, you should use one of the three methods that start with [`initWithBytes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCFHH), or, to create an autoreleased `NSData` object, use one of the class methods that start with [`dataWithBytes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytes%3alength%3a)

UPDATE: I think that if you want to create an `NSImage` directly from an `NSData`, the data needs to include the appropriate headers/magic numbers so that `NSImage` can figure out what the representation is. You should look at [`NSBitmapImageRep`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the [Images chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-BCIBBFGJ) of the Cocoa Drawing Guide for raw image data.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no practical way to create an NSData object without, at some point, handling each pixel explicitly, as can be done if I use NSBitmapImageRep.  Every permutation of handing off the pointer seems to give me casting problems.  And of course, there is still the problem of taking an NSBitmapImageRep object and converting it to an NSImage.  (As far as I can tell from the documentation, this means saving to disk or to a cache as a known format with header info, which is what I have already done successfully using libtiff.)  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!